# Header/Nav/Logo placement

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to develop a specific design for a webpage. I'm wanting to overlap a logo in the shape of a shield, bottom centered on a header image. I then want to place navigation on both sides of the logo bordering the bottom of the header image. The innermost nav items I want to, instead of being boxes, contour to the shape of the logo using something akin to shape-outside. I have to admit, this one is stumping me.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Kindly share the code snippet of what you tried so far.

Comment: kindly share your website code ...